# User Environment Variable with airflow.webserver.defaultUser.password

Tags: kubernetes, airflow, jinja2, kubernetes-helm

I am using [the Helm chart for Apache Airflow](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/helm-chart/stable/index.html) and trying to set the password of the default user to the value of an environment variable:

```yaml
airflow:
  env:
    - name: PASSWORD
      value: Hello, World!
  webserver:
    defaultUser:
      password: $PASSWORD
```

However, this is setting the password to literally `$PASSWORD` instead of `Hello, World!`.

I have tried other things like `password: ${PASSWORD}` to no avail.

Comment: Use it as `$(PASSWORD)`

Comment: @P...., I mention in the last line of the question that I tried that, and it didn't work.

Comment: Ok, although I can't see in any line saying you used $(...), note the bracket style.

Comment: @P...., my bad! It had been a long day, and my eyes deceived me. It worked! Thanks! I will accept your comment as the answer if you post it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use as follow, this is as described in [official examples](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/inject-data-application/define-environment-variable-container/#using-environment-variables-inside-of-your-config).

```
$(PASSWORD)
```